# Set of necessary cuts out of subset of edges to make node unreachable

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm interested in finding the possible sets of edges that must be cut from a directed graph to disconnect a node from the source, but only certain edges can be cut.

I need to find the necessary combinations of blue lines that must be cut to disconnect a yellow node from the purple node (0). For example, node 2 can never be isolated as it is connected to the purple node by black arrows. However, node 3 can be isolated by cutting `[(1, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3)]` or by cutting `[(1, 3), (4, 3), (4, 5)]`.

I believe this is related to the critical path problem, or maybe the min-cut problem. It's not quite the same as the minimum cut problem as (a) only certain edges can be cut and (b) there might be alternative cuts which aren't minimal but can't be reduced.

So far I've been able to generate the set of all permutations of cut/uncut edges which disconnect a node, but I want to narrow it down to the smallest necessary conditions.

[image: A simple directed graph with blue and black edges]

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
for i in range(6):
    G.add_node(i)
G.add_edge(0, 1)
G.add_edge(1, 0)
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(3, 2, p=True)
G.add_edge(1, 3, p=True)
G.add_edge(3, 1, p=True)
G.add_edge(5, 3, p=True)
G.add_edge(3, 5, p=True)
G.add_edge(4, 3, p=True)
G.add_edge(3, 4, p=True)
G.add_edge(5, 4, p=True)
G.add_edge(4, 5, p=True)
G.add_edge(4, 0)
G.add_edge(0, 4)

node_colour = ["tab:purple", "lightgreen", "yellow", "yellow", "lightgreen", "lightgreen"]
cut = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "p")
edge_colour = ["blue" if edge in cut.keys() else "black" for edge in G.edges]
nx.draw(
    G, with_labels=True, node_size=500, node_color=node_colour, edge_color=edge_colour
)
plt.show()

# evaluate if a node is unreachable if *all* blue edges are cut
G2 = G.copy()
blue_edges = nx.get_edge_attributes(G2, "p").keys()
G2.remove_edges_from(blue_edges)
unreachable = []
for node in [2, 3]:
    try:
        nx.algorithms.shortest_path(G2, 0, node)
    except:
        unreachable.append(node)
```

Comment: The number of such cuts can be exponentially large.

Comment: Use https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_edge.html to contract nodes that cannot be cut. And then you've at least simplified the problem.

Comment: You may want to use another color for your edges, or at least thicker lines. I may just be blind, but it took me way too long to see that some of the edges were dark blue, making it difficult to understand your example.

Comment: @btilly I initially had a go at approaching the problem by contracting edges that weren't blue but then you get multiedges and you can't necessarily reconstruct which edges needed to be cut in the original

Comment: @base12 The answer is all of them to correspond to a cut in the contracted graph. For the original graph to be cut, its contraction must also be cut. And any surviving edge will result in that edge in the contraction.